# How do I write the equivalent of a FORTRAN CHARACTER declaration in C#?

Tags: c#

I am writing a program in C# that has to access a proprietary FORTRAN DLL (REFPROP) via a wrapper or interface.   If I had been writing a FORTRAN routine to access REFPROP direct, I would have declared a particular variable like this:

```
character (len=255) ::  herrA
```

Can anyone tell me please how to write the same declaration in C#?

Comment: The short answer is `string herrA;`, but you should probably take a look at the wrapper to see how it does it.

Comment: I get the feeling you already know about `string herrA;`. So what are the specialities of your fortran declaration that you need to translate to C#? Is it just a string with a max length of 255?

Comment: Thank you '500' and 'Nerd Pride'.

Comment: Sorry - sent that bit in error - more follows.

Comment: Thank you, both.   Here is as much information as may be useful: 1. the userguide for the FORTRAN DLL (REFPROP) specifies herr as character*255; 2. The c# environment I am using is SharpDevelop which is 32-bit; 3. So I am  modifying an existing 64-bit wrapper to suit C#; 4. at presesent the REFPROP subroutine call has herr in the argument list as follows: string herr (but can change that if preferable); 5. The C# application that I am writing has herr declared as follows: string herr = "";   6. all builds Ok but at Run get an error indication and herr is blank -should be text describing error.